# Actual device and device preview on page inspector

Tags: javascript, html, ios, web-inspector

I'm having an issue where the width of a div will look fine on the device preview in the page inspector (Apple iPhone X). When I look at it on the actual device (an iPhone 11), the width of the div is longer. Specifically, I'm talking about the width of the datepicker (see photos below).

Is there a way to preview for an iPhone 11 (I did not see this option in page inspector). I'm not sure why the actual width of the div is changing that much.

**Inspector:**

[image]

**Inspector specifically set at iphone 11 width/height:**

[image]

**Actual:**

[image]

I'm trying to keep the calendar date-bar to not be too big on mobile, with this css (I'm using media queries with standard break points):

```
 #calendarContainer {
   width:23%;
   text-align: center;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: What's the code that's causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

iPhone 11 viewport is 414 x 896, so change resolution to 414 x 896 in page inspector

Comment: edited question. Preview at 414 x 896 still looks fine in inspector, and different in actuality?